# Вызов статического метода перед остановкой программы

Tags: c++, static, singleton

Задача состоит в том, чтобы вызвать определенный **статический** метод перед остановкой программы из-за неизвестной ошибки. С моими знаниями, я предполагаю, что это невозможно. Что я имею ввиду ?

Предположим, что у нас есть класс A:

```cpp
class A
{
public:

    A() { std::cout << " A()" << std::endl; }
   ~A() { std::cout << "~A()" << std::endl; }
};
```

При инициализации данного класса где бы ни было, обязательно, при выходе из скоупа, или других сценариев, будет вызван деструктор этого класса (за это мы и любим С++). Например:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    A a;
}

// Console output

 A()
~A()
```

Тут все понятно. А вот при объявление статических объектов все немгого по другому:

```cpp
// ...

static A a;

// ...
```

Объекты со статическим временем жизни будут уничтожены **при завершении работы приложения**. С этим так же все понятно. И тут появляется проблема. У меня есть класс, который имеет лишь статические функции. Понятно, что у класса удалены все конструкторы, деструкторы и операторы копирования и перемещения. Назовем этот класс **SessionManager**:

*PS Этот класс приводится только в качестве примера*

```cpp
class SessionManager
{
public:

    SessionManager() = delete;
    SessionManager &operator=(const SessionManager &) = delete;
    SessionManager &operator=(SessionManager &&) = delete;
    SessionManager(const SessionManager &) = delete;
    SessionManager(SessionManager &&) = delete;
   ~SessionManager() = delete;

    static void stop();
    static void start();

    static void method_1();
    static void method_2();
    static void method_3();
    static void method_n();

private: 

    static void worker();

private:

    static int arg_1;
    static int arg_2;
    static int arg_3;
    static int arg_n;

    static std::thread worker_thread;

};
```

Метод `start` запускает 1 поток, в котором и будет производиться главная логика класса. **Обязательно** до остановки программы, метод `stop` должен быть вызван! Если этого не сделать, критически важная информация будет потеряна. Но, что будет, если пользователь забудет вызвать данный метод - потеря информации... Как можно решить эту проблему ?

---

*Мысли вслух*

Первое, что приходит мне в голову - это переписать класс, а именно сделать его нестатичным, а в деструкторе вызывать метод `stop` на всякий случай. Но этот класс должен быть инициализирован только 1 раз, что наводит на мысль о синглтонном паттерне (что, честно говоря, не радует).

Comment: В вопросе не отражены причины (сомнения) по которым Вам не подходят деструкторы статических объектов, которые вызываются при завершении программы или при выгрузке динамической библиотеки.

Comment: ну дык, типичный одиночка... почему мысли об этом «не радуют»?

Comment: @Fat-Zer изначально, класс был написан как в примере выше, и при написании синглтона, придется переделывать сам класс, плюс, как минимум, придется исправлять и строчки кода, в котором вызываются методы этого класса (этих строк кода очень много)

Comment: Все эти важные действия следует выполнить в особом **нестатическом** методе - деструкторе объекта, занимающегося "главной логикой".

Comment: @user7860670 Смогли бы Вы дать пример, ибо не полностью понимаю, что Вы  имеете ввиду

Comment: Ну а что тут непонятного - если если следует выполнить какие-то действия по финализации, то их следует выполнять в деструкторе.

Comment: @bbdd, дело твоё, но если это приложение, то скорей всего рефакторинг (даже вручную) займёт меньше времени, чем написание поста + каждое место будет вызывать ошибку компиляции, так что отловить их будет не сложно... если это библиотека или всё равно лень менять, то можно сделать гебридный вариант, превратив объект в одиночку и оставив текущий API для совместимости...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Способ первый - создайте маленький объект, основная задача которого только в деструкторе позвать нужную функцию.

```
сlass Late
{
public:
  ~Late() { SessionManager::stop(); }
};
```

и теперь в main просто пишем

```
int main()
{
//..

Late l;
//..
}
```

И все. Можно для этой же цели использовать std::unique_ptr с пользовательским деструктором. Но тут на любителя. Главное, вставить создание этой переменной в нужном месте в начале (можно и в самом начале, а можно даже как глобальную переменную объявить, тут нужно смотреть как красивее).

Второй способ. Есть такая функция - [atexit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/atexit) которой просто нужно передать функцию, которую нужно выполнить по завершению программы. Плюсы этого способа, что вызывать эту функцию можно с любого места кода и можно регистрировать много таких функций (они все отработают).

```
// там где понятно, что нужно вызвать стоп
const int result = std::atexit(SessionManager::stop);

if (result != 0) {
    std::cerr << "Registration failed\n";
    // обработаем ошибку
}
```

я бы этот код в start добавил бы

Comment: `std::atexit` вызывается если программа завершилась нормально. В вопросе речь идёт про ошибку, поэтому я бы использовал [`std::set_terminate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/set_terminate)

Comment: если это исключение, то, да. Просто "неизвестная ошибка" - это не обязательно исключение. С другой стороны, если пришло sigsegv (что тоже вполне себе "неизвестная ошибка", то тут вызывать что то уже не стоит).

Comment: Изначально думал и про первый Ваш пример, но хотелось бы, если есть возможность, скрыть от пользователя, вызов `stop`. Чтобы сама библиотека заботилась о том, чтобы завершить поток успешно.

Comment: @KoVadim для `sigsterm` например, есть обработчик, который и выполняет остановку.

Comment: @bbdd для многих библиотек это нормально, написать "не забудьте в конце вызвать нашу функцию очистки".

Comment: @KoVadim полностью с Вами согласен. Но и Вы и я знамем программистов.

Comment: Интересно то, что при просмотре, уже не помню, какой то библиотеки, которая также работает с потоками, не имеет публичного функционала остановки потока (не используют синглтон)

Comment: есть такие. Например, SDL. Там делают страшное - `#define main SDL_main`. Когда я первый раз это увидел, то хотелось объяснить разрабам, что не стоит так делать.

Comment: Кстати, глобальные деструкторы единицы трансляции вызываются как раз из atexit